# Java var-args wired behavoir on widening

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am reading about  methods that include var-arg parameters...

it's not legal to declare the following 
(as var-arg is implicitly passed as array i.e. will be a method duplicate)

```
void m1(int... i) {}
void m1(int[] i) {}
```

but the flowing is legal to declare:

```
void m1(int... i) {}
void m1(Integer... i) {}
```

however, these methods can only be legally invoked with arrays of the same types
like:

```
m1(new Integer[]{});
m1(new int[]{});
```

and **not** with:

```
m1(2, 3);                           //Compile ERR: The method m1(int[]) is ambiguous                
m1(new Integer(2), new Integer(3)); //Compile ERR: The method m1(int[]) is ambiguous
```

**yet** `void m1(int... i){}` is invoked when called with:

```
m1((byte)1,(short)2);     
m1(new Byte((byte)1), new Byte((byte)1));

//Both compile fine and the method 
//void m1(int... i) {} is invoked
```

My **question is**, if `(byte)1,(short)2` or  `new Byte((byte)1), new Byte((byte)1)`are passed as `int[]`

why it does not behave the same for `m1(2, 3)` or `m1(new Integer(2), new Integer(3));`?

Answer (score 1):

as you are reading you might be aware there var-arg parameter process is Generic parameter process at runtime and there are some restrictions of casting when working with Generic read those [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) and for your following query

```
m1((byte)1,(short)2);//for this it will automatically wrap your digits in non primitive class object read boxing conversation
m1(new Byte((byte)1), new Byte((byte)1));//for this it is working as you are creating non primitive objects
```

[Boxing Conversation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: `m1(new Integer(3), new Integer(4));` gives compile error "The method m1(int[]) is ambiguous" or "The method m1(Integer[]) is ambiguous" depending on the order of m1(int...) and m1(Integer...) declaration

Answer (score 1):

Remember Widening beats Boxing beats Var-Args

(byte)1,(short)2  cannot be widened to int, int and then Integer, Integer (Widen Then Box) - Costly or heavy for JVM. short and byte can easily be widened to int so int... is called.

new Byte((byte)1), new Byte((byte)1)  cannot be typecast to (Integer,Integer) i.e Unbox to byte,then widen to int and again box to Integer(Widen then Box) - Heavy. But it can be easily unboxed to byte and widened to int(Box Then Widen is not heavy) so int... is called.

In above two cases int[] will be called.

m1(2, 3) can be Boxed to Integer[] or passed to int[] - Ambiguity
m1(new Integer(2), new Integer(3)) can be passed to Integer[] or unboxed to int.

Answer (score 0):

`Byte` doesn't extend `Integer`. So it wouldn't be valid to call a method `void m1(Integer i) {}` by doing `m1(new Byte(1))` (with or without the varargs).

It works with `int` and `byte` because `byte` can be referenced as an `int`.

Comment: I've run it before assume 
m1((byte)1,(byte)2)
int...       CALLED
 m1(new Byte((byte)1), new Byte((byte)1))
int...       CALLED